# Regular Expression Not Matching Correctly

Tags: java, regex

Hi I have to match a pattern like below

```
{digit 0-1 or A}:{digit 0-1 or A}:{digit 0-1 or A}|{digit 0-1 or A}:{digit 0-1 or A}:{digit 0-1 or A}|{digit 0-1 or A}:{digit 0-1 or A}:{digit 0-1 or A}
```

I am using the following code -

```
String accMatrixPattern = "\\d{1,1}|[A]:\\d{1,1}|[A]:\\d{1,1}|[A]|[A]:\\d{1,1}|[A]"; 
String accMatrx = "1:A:1|0:1:1|0:1:1";
```

If I am using only "`\\d{1,1}|[A]`";
it is working but not combined.

Please suggest How to match Regular Expression

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're trying to match just 0, 1 or A in each position, you can use:

```
String accMatrixPattern = "[01A]:[01A]:[01A]\\|[01A]:[01A]:[01A]\\|[01A]:[01A]:[01A]";
```

---

If you want to take values, -1, 0, 1, A:

```
String accMatrixPattern = "([01A]|-1):([01A]|-1):([01A]|-1)\\|([01A]|-1):([01A]|-1):([01A]|-1)\\|([01A]|-1):([01A]|-1):([01A]|-1)";
```

Comment: Thank u very much. It is working. I will accept the answer after 9 minutes :)

Comment: @ BTW if I want to take -1 to 1 range then how to do it??

Answer (score 2):

```
String regex = "[01A]:[01A]:[01A](\\|[01A]:[01A]:[01A]){2}";
```

This matches one character (either a 0 or a 1 or the letter A), followed by a colon, followed by another character like the first, followed by a colon, followed by a third character like the first.

Then it takes a | character (note that it's escaped), followed by the same thing again but twice.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the `|` on the whole string, so, with brackets added to indicate how grouping will happen, your regex would look something like this:

```
"(\\d{1,1})|([A]:\\d{1,1})|([A]:\\d{1,1})|([A])|([A]:\\d{1,1})|([A])"
```

So it would match a string consisting of only `1` or `A:0` or `A:1` or ...

So you should add some brackets to make it process it correctly.

The `{1,1}` is redundant, you can just use `\\d`.

`A` doesn't have to be inside `[]`.

You need to escape the `|` if you're talking about the literal character.

```
"(\\d|A):(\\d|A):(\\d|A)\|(\\d|A):(\\d|A):(\\d|A)\|(\\d|A):(\\d|A):(\\d|A)"
```

You can now use some `{}` to cancel out the redundancy.

```
"(\\d|A):(\\d|A)(:(\\d|A)\|(\\d|A):(\\d|A)){2}"
```

For only digits `0-1`, using `[01A]` (as suggested in the other answers) is probably better.

```
"[01A]:[01A](:[01A]\|[01A]:[01A]){2}"
```

Comment: Yes I was getting that but did not be able to put bracket; Thanks for your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
[01A]:[01A]:[01A](?:\\|[01A]:[01A]:[01A]){2}
```

?: to specify this is a non capturing group